# Performance Issues with Razor Syntax in Foreach loop, and ModelState permanently false

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I've got a list of addresses, of which none, one or many can be assigned to an account. The way that has been designed to show these, is a list of checkboxes. So I've written the following razor C# syntax:-

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox-set">
                    <label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.IsSelected, new { @onclick = "CheckOpenOrdersForUserDeliveryAddress(this,'" + Model.UserID + "'," + Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].InternetAccountNumber + "," + Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.Id + ");" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.Address.Address)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].InternetAccountNumber
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].InternetAccountNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
              @Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.Address.Address
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

At present, there are 712 items in this list, and the rendering of the page with this data is c. 1.3 to 1.5 minutes! As soon as I remove all of the @Html.... the page loads in 9.2 seconds - which for us is fine.

So my first question, is, what is causing this 90 second delay in loading the page, and making Google Chrome flash up asking me if I want to kill the page?

Secondly, I tried converting all of these @Html... into normal HTML input tags, and as I said, the page loads in around 9 seconds. On submitting the form though, the ModelState is always invalid, as the property IsSelected on the below is apparently "set to 'on'", even though this property is a bool. Can anyone suggest a way around this either?

**The Model**

```
public class AccountDeliveryAddressModel
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public AccountLevel UserRole { get; set; }
    public List<AccountDeliveryAddress> AccountDeliveryAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class AccountDeliveryAddress
{
    public int InternetAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public DeliveryAddressModel DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
}
```

So my two questions are:-

1. Why does the @Html.... methods make the page slow to a minute and a half?
2. If I change these to standard `<input>` tags and replicate what the razor would print, how can I ensure the model is valid, if it suggests that the checkbox values are being set to 'on', rather than true/false?

**Edit**
The issue with the checkboxes loading slowly only appears to happen in Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m.

**Edit 2**
This also only occurs in Chrome, when jquery-validation javascript files are included. But as per the model above, there is no validation attributes on the model. I notice though, that `data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required."` is added to every input?

Thanks!

Comment: The bool has a required val b/c it's not a "bool?". Since a bool is either true or false, not null, in essence it is required.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. Would that explain why 'on' is being passed for a checked box?

Comment: Not sure. I don't know what you're doing when not using html helpers.

Comment: If `on` is being passed by your manual checkbox input, its because you have not set the `value="true"` attribute. You should also be creating an associated hidden input with `value="false"`. Inspect the html generated by the `CheckBoxFor()` method and duplicate it manually.

Comment: And the `data-val-required=".."` (and `data-val="true"`) attributes are added because a `bool` is always required (it must have a value of `true` or `false` and cannot be `null`)

Comment: Out of interest, why did this question get downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the check box to be required you could try setting the data-val="false" like

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.IsSelected, new { @onclick = "CheckOpenOrdersForUserDeliveryAddress(this,'" + Model.UserID + "'," + Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].InternetAccountNumber + "," + Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.Id + ");", data_val = "false" })
```

Comment: This was my checkbox code in the end:-

`<input type="checkbox" id="AccountDeliveryAddresses_@(i)__DeliveryAddress_IsSelected" name="AccountDeliveryAddressesSelected" onclick="CheckOpenOrdersForUserDeliveryAddress(this, '@Model.UserID',@Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].InternetAccountNumber,@Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.Id)" @(Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.IsSelected ? "checked=checked" : "") value="@Model.AccountDeliveryAddresses[i].DeliveryAddress.Id" />`

It passes a list of integer to the controller, and these ID's are stored in the database.